# jQuery on() method only works indirectly via childSelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Any ideas what could be the reason that the code

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_add', function(e) {alert("test");});
```

works, but

```
$('.btn_add').on('click', function(e) {alert("test");});
```

does not?

Thanks,

Comment: that is called event delegation.

Comment: It's because the `.btn_add` element is not part of the DOM when the handler is added. For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is event delegation:

Syntax is :

```
$(staticparent).on(event, selector, fn);
```

in this syntax `selector` is not a part of DOM, what it means when your page loaded this element was not there in the dom but after some js code execution this `.btn_add` element added in the DOM. so any event bound on page load won't be registered for this element.

so in your case if `.btn_add` is created dynamically then you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent, body or to document itself.

Here is a test case for **event not bound on dynamic content**.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('<button/>', {
    text: "Dynamic button"
  }).appendTo('body');
  alert(this.textContent);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Static</button>
```

Here is a test case for **event bound on dynamic content**.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('<button/>', {
    text: "Dynamic button"
  }).appendTo('body');
  alert(this.textContent);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Static</button>
```